# css: сдвигать текст при переносе на новую строку

Tags: css, строки, html, padding

Приветствую

Подскажите, возможно ли с помощью css для многострокового текста задать смещение текста второй и более высокой строки относительно первой?

т.е. чтобы

```
ну просто очень длинный текст, ужас
```

превращался бы не в

```
ну просто
очень длинный текст,
ужас
```

а в

```
ну просто
  очень длинный
  текст, ужас
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2833068/5812238

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) с отрицательным значением:

```
text-indent: -10px;
margin-left: 10px;
```

Сниппет:

```css
div {
  text-indent: -10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>ну просто очень длинный текст, ужас</div>
```

Comment: да, text-indent похоже то что надо
надо напильником доработать только для своих нужд немного

Answer (score 1):

может быть **white-space:pre-wrap** ?

```css
p{
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  display:inline;
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p> Lorem ipsum 
            dolor sit amet 
            consectetur adipisicing.
</p>
```

это пример того что можно было сделать в этом аспекте

```css
p{
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  display:inline;
  color:red;
  position:relative;
}
p:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  bottom:-2px;
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  background:url(http://dizayni.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Dizayni.ru_Globe.png);
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<p> Lorem ipsum 
            dolor sit amet 
            consectetur adipisicing.
</p>
```

хоть стописят пробелов

```css
p{
  width:300px;
  margin:auto;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem, 
ipsum dolor
sit amet sectetur
adipi sicing elit elitium 
Dolores natus harum laborum
magni aliquam fuga neque aut inve
quis dolorum laboriosam molesti,
eaque corporis impedit labore
excepturi. Numquam, iste 
temporibus. Cupiditate
labore atque simil
ique nostrum
magnam. 
Iusto 
</p>
```